# How do I fix the index nil with target issue I have?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I want to move this part to the place where the persons mouse is after 3 seconds, and I have a spring to move it there. When I set it to go to a province on the map it generally does so, but that's only when I set it myself in the script. I get an error on line 14 saying: Workspace.Regiments.Regiment.Engine:14: attempt to index nil with 'Target', and I'm not sure why it refuses to work. The rendition of my code being used at the moment also uses Roblox's provided code for this(still does not work).

```
local regiment = script.Parent

local attach = Instance.new("Attachment")

local partattach = Instance.new("Attachment")
partattach.Parent = regiment

-- movement part

regiment.ClickDetector.MouseHoverEnter:Connect(function(player)
    wait(3)
    local mouse = player:GetMouse()
    
    if mouse.Target and mouse.Target.Parent then
        attach.Parent = mouse.Target
        print("location set, click the regiment")
    end
end)

regiment.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()

    regiment.SpringConstraint.Attachment1 = attach
    regiment.SpringConstraint.Attachment0 = partattach
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it says attempt to index nil with Target, that's referring to the mouse

That's most likely due to this being a ServerScript and when you call `player:GetMouse()` on the server it returns nil.

The solution to this is to have the server call a remote function and for the client to return the target

```lua
-- client
local remoteFunction = path.to.remoteFunction

remoteFunction.OnClientInvoke = function()
    return game.Players.LocalPlayers:GetMouse().Target
end
```

```lua
-- server
...
regiment.ClickDetector.MouseHoverEnter:Connect(function(player)
    wait(3)
    local target = path.to.remoteFunction:InvokeClient(player)
    
    if target and target.Parent then
        attach.Parent = mouse.Target
        print("location set, click the regiment")
    end
end)
...
```

Comment: There's no longer errors, but the part itself refuses to move. Why could that be?

Comment: Could you make sure that your SpringConstraint is setup properly?